Creating a reduced-length resampling of a numpy array
I have a numpy array of a certain length, and want to produce a much shorter array, where each value in the shorter array is aggregated based on a bin of values in the original array. In my specific case, this happens to be an audio signal and the function I'm applying is a max over each bin.
It feels like there must be a function like numpy.interp or scipy.interpolate.interp1d which could make this easier. I swear there must be a simpler/cleaner way to do this with a numpy or scipy built-in.
This is the code I write now:
# assume a is an np.array with len(a) == 510
shorten_length = 50
a_shortened = np.zeros(len(a) // shorten_length)

for i in range(len(a_shortened)):
    slice_end = min(len(a), (i+1) * shorten_length) - 1
    _bin_max = np.max(a[i * shorten_length:slice_end+1])
    a_shortened[i] = _bin_max


I think you are finding something similar to this post.

Good thing about using ufunc answers like in the dupe target is that it's extensible to basically any ufunc

As long as you are dropping the last slice (when it's smaller than shorten_length),
you can use this approach:
valid_length = len(a) - len(a) % shorten_length
a_shortened = a[:valid_length].reshape(-1, shorten_length).max(axis=1)

No array copy is involved during slicing or reshaping.
